# Android: Is it possible to launch an application in portrait mode in landscape screen

Tags: android, rotation, orientation, landscape-portrait, portrait

Let say I have an application designed to open other applications just like a apps screen on android phones. I wanted to keep the device in landscape. At the same time, if other applications designed to be working in a portrait mode, I wanted to show as Portrait in a landscape screen rather than stretch the application to fit within the landscape screen.

This is the screenshot as an example:

The red shape is the application running in portrait. 
The black shape is the screen of the device in landscape.

At the moment, my application will load the portrait app in full screen mode which the red shape will be fill the whole screen.

[image: Screenshot of the device in landscape]

P.S. The device I am using can be rooted.

My launcher at the moment can load the application and cause the application to rotate into portrait on a Portrait screen.

Answer (score 0):

Spending days of finding. The solution is to root the device and calling wm size 300x800 or any number as a su privilege in code.

The way to root the emulator to test can be found in here:

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/148841/attempt-to-root-avd-running-android-4-4-5-1-is-failing

Use the appropriate API Level as stated in the answer. Otherwise it may not work.

The way to call the su command :

https://github.com/neoimale/android-screen-mock/blob/master/ScreenMock/src/com/dianping/screenmock/MainActivity.java